# Jenkins - load global pipeline library from filesystem instead of SCM?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I can't find anything in the docs on how to do this - anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems it is currently not possible. But you can easily init a local git repository and use it as SCM without any remote hostings.
To init a git repo use the following commands in the root directory of your shared library (for example C:\Users\Jenkins\pipeline-shared-library-test):

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "init"
```

Then in `Manage Jenkins->Configure System->Global Pipeline Libraries` you can point `Project Repository` to you local repo using a file URI `file:///c:/Users/Jenkins/pipeline-shared-library-test`
This approach works fine for me.
[image: shared library form local git repo]

Comment: Thanks, this does work, unfortunately not with perforce.

Answer (score 4):

You can use File System SCM plugin to load your library from file system.
Once you have installed this plugin, use "Legacy SCM" in your library configuration to set a path and choose "master" as default version. Can not use Load implicitly, so  explicit configuration should be done in the pipeline.

As a reference, I read this approach in this slides https://www.slideshare.net/roidelapluie/jenkins-shared-libraries-workshop.