# Jenkins shared libraries, multiple versions of same class

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to basically load two versions of the same Jenkins [shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/). This library mostly contains helper functions for Jenkins and the pipeline.

The reason for requiring two versions is that many of our pipelines have some amount of prologue/epilogue, which usually use the latest version of these helper functions, and in between, a specific project's pipeline is called, which may require an older version of the helper functions. This way, updating the helper functions doesn't require modifying older pipelines.

So far I'm trying something like this:

```
def latestlib = library identifier: 'jenkinslib-latest@default', retriever: legacySCM(
    [$class: 'SubversionSCM', 
        locations: [[
            depthOption: 'infinity', 
            ignoreExternalsOption: false, 
            remote: "svn://../jenkinslib/branches/<latest-branch>"
        ]], 
        workspaceUpdater: [
            $class: 'CheckoutUpdater'
        ]
    ]
)

def olderlib = library identifier: 'jenkinslib-old@default', retriever: legacySCM(
    [$class: 'SubversionSCM', 
        locations: [[
            depthOption: 'infinity', 
            ignoreExternalsOption: false, 
            remote: "svn://../jenkinslib/branches/<old-branch>"
        ]], 
        workspaceUpdater: [
            $class: 'CheckoutUpdater'
        ]
    ]
)
```

The library (both versions of it) has a class `HelperFunctions` at src/org/jenkinslib/HelperFunctions.groovy which looks something like this:

```
package org.jenkinslib

class HelperFunctions implements Serializable {
 ...
}
```

Back to the pipeline, I try to create instances of both `HelperFunction` classes:

```
def hf = latestlib.org.jenkinslib.HelperFunctions.new()
def hf2 = olderlib.org.jenkinslib.HelperFunctions.new()
```

This fails with:

java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/CpsGroovyShell$CleanGroovyClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "org/jenkinslib/HelperFunctions"

Which makes sense, I suppose.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the title of the question alone and according to the [Jenkins doc *Dependencies and Class Loading, The plugin class loader hierarchy*](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/plugin-development/dependencies-and-class-loading/#the-plugin-class-loader-hierarchy) it should be possible with plugins:

> Each (enabled) plugin gets its own `ClassLoader`. **It is possible for two distinct plugins to define a class of the same name**, so long as neither depends on the other.

(Emphasis by me.)

With Groovy apparently searching its complete [`classpath`](https://groovy-lang.org/groovyconsole.html#GroovyConsole-Command-lineOptionsandArguments) I see no other way atm. See [*Writing Pipeline-Compatible Plugins*](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/plugin-development/pipeline-integration/).

Answer (score 0):

Couple things that (almost) worked, to varying extents:

One thing to note is that modifying the library versions on a per-branch basis such that instantiations in the OP look more like this:

```
def hf = latestlib.org.jenkinslib.HelperFunctions.new()
def hf2 = olderlib.org.jenkinslib2.HelperFunctions.new()
```

(note the different package names)

... appears to work. I'm not overly experienced with java, so as far as I understand it, this would require modifying all the `package` statements in the library per-branch, which is not great.

Since these groovy files are all just text, it's possible to do any number of manual "name-mangling" things, where you could either modify the package name or even the class name on the fly, and then load the shared lib from disk instead of SCM as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51325467/2002288 (or similar).

Another approach I tried was one that involved code like this:

```
String sourceFile = readFile("./...branch1.../HelperFunctions.groovy");
Class groovyClass = new GroovyClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader()).parseClass(sourceFile);
GroovyObject hf = (GroovyObject) groovyClass2.newInstance();
```

... and again for the other branch/version of `HelperFunctions`. This sort of works, but I believe code loaded this way doesn't undergo the Jenkins CPS transformations, and so if you mix native jenkins stuff (like `sh`) (which is CPS transformed) into your class, you'll get errors like this:

expected to call org.jenkinslib.HelperFunctions.GetBuildTool but wound up catching sh; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/pipeline-cps-method-mismatches/

The plugin approach suggested by @Gerold Broser is likely a workable suggestion, but I didn't try it myself.

What does work, I believe, is using the native pipeline `load` command, *provided that your groovy files only contain free functions*.  That's giving up something in terms of utility, and really giving up on a "library" in favor of a pile of functions, but checks the most boxes for me at the moment. Briefly, this solution looks like:

```
def old_functions = load '.../branch1/.../HelperFunctions.groovy'
def new_functions = load '.../branch2/.../HelperFunctions.groovy'

println(old_functions.f())
println(new_functions.f())
```